# $\Bbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}×\Bbb{Z}$. Why? $×$ is external direct product.

Tags: group-theory

$\Bbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}×\Bbb{Z}$. Why? $×$ is external direct product.
I couldn't find any way to find the reason behind it. I know all the basic theory behind isomorphism. Please help me out.

Comment: Do you know what is a divisible group?

Comment: No. My professor didn't teach divisible group. Still gave this problem in exam.

Comment: $R$ and $Z$ are group under addition of reals and integers respectively.

Comment: So isomorphic, or not, as additive groups, right? I suppose you should write this more clearly.

Comment: Yeah  @Dietrich Burde

Comment: Or even more simply, $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ has non-trivial finite subgroups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "compact" doesn't make sense in this context (not preserved by group isomorphisms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ satisfies $\forall x \exists y: y+y=x$. $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{Z}$ does not satisfy this formula, so the groups are not isomorphic.